# Equation of a surface R

Tags: r

In aeronautical engineering, the height above the runway plane (Z) is related to:

1. Down range distance from the takeoff initiation (X)
2. Runway length used by fully loaded aircraft (Y).

We wish to find z=f(x,y) from an array of observed points z, at known values of x and y.  z is linear in x and in y.  The current solution involves fitting a family of functions z=f(x).  Then, using the coefficients in the family, doing a second regression to get z=f(x,y).  My guess is there is a much better way to do it. This code has been around a while and was probably cobbed together and never rethought.  The observations look like this:
[climb performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13XhH.png)

The code to obtain f(x,y) looks like:

```
X <- seq(6000,10000,1000);
Y <- seq(4000,6000,500);

Z <- c(145, 200, 254, 307, 360,
       118, 165, 213, 260, 310,
        90, 130, 172, 213, 254,
        67, 102, 137, 175, 210,
        50,  80, 110, 140, 170);
dim(Z) <- c(5,5);

Fxy <- coef( lm( t( coef( lm( Z ~ X ) ) ) ~ Y ) );  #2x2 matrix

x <- c(1,6000);  # test values
y <- c(1,4000);

z <- y %*% Fxy %*% x;
z;
```

This solution works fine but it seems that there should be a way to do this without sequential regressions.
It's worth mentioning that X and Y are not always the same length and Z is not always square.
We have no R wizards here but many curious folks that have used this with a variety of formulae including quadratics and exponentials.  If there's a "right" way to do it we'd use it in all of our code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if your response Z is linear to either x or y, you can perform a multiple linear regression with an interaction term x:y.

```
# make a data frame containing all observations
df <- expand.grid(x = X, y = Y)
df$z <- c(Z)

# fit a linear model with interaction term
fit <- lm(z ~ x + y + x:y, data = df)
# alternatively
fit <- lm(z ~ x * y, data = df) # see ?lm

# Call:
# lm(formula = z ~ x + y + x:y, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x            y          x:y  
# -2.703e+02    1.011e-01    2.276e-02   -1.188e-05  


# predict
df.test <- cbind.data.frame(x = x, y = y)
predict(fit, newdata = df.test)

# the results is the same: one value for one obs
# 1         2 
# -270.1561  142.3600
```

in addition, if you data contain missing values(not equal length, not square ...), I think it would be better to manage your data if you organise them into data frames, where each row represents a record for related observations.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.  The data frame on independent observations is a good idea as well, though it will have several copies of X and Y.  That's actually the most interesting take away.  If the data is structured that way the length of X vs Y is irrelevant.